# sencha Touch:how to shorten axis labels

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-charts

Is there any way to shorten the axis labels in sencha touch chart. As my axis labels are very long.Is it possible to show axis labels in two rows.

Please help me regarding this,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with below code and it working fine for me.

```
label: {
        renderer: function(val) {
        if (val.length > 10) {
        return val.substring(0, 10) + "...";
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is possible to show the label in two rows, but you can format the label using following code:

```
label : {
    renderer : function(val) {
        return val;
    }
}
```

May be you want to truncate the label length to 3 characters, and have a legend to display the full forms of abbreviations.

Comment: Thanks Hrishikesh for your quick reply but iam renderending the axis labels dynamically, so we don't know what exactly the length of the labels will be.

Comment: check the lengths and truncate to three.